# Raised bed soil problem

Tags: mold

I’m finding white dry clumps in soil. [image]Last year nothing would grow in this area. I think it may be a mold. My question is how to treat.

Comment: Yeah, that very much looks like a mold or fungus.    What did you try and grow in that area?  https://dengarden.com/gardening/Moldy-Potting-Soil is an interesting read - and one of its conclusions is to mix it back into the soil.    This course of action makes some sense to me.  (A good soil does have fungi and a whole microbiome - yours is out of wack).  Note this is a comment - I do not have the knowledge to provide a proper answer.

Comment: Last year it was bell peppers.